# Is there any iTunes Connect API?

Tags: app-store-connect

What I am actually looking for is to get the app download statistics from iTunes connect. Ideally a dashboard would be possible with a full API.

There was this idea where some coding could be done in the iphone app section so as to determine if the app is being launched for the first time and so fire a url with the flag. Rather than intercepting or proxying the the communications from the iOS iTunes connect app, I would like to retrieve an app's download statistics from iTunes connect itself.

Is there a public API or private framework to reverse engineer this?

Comment: Moderators note: scraping any web page or service is always technically possible and could be explicitly against the terms of service. We’re not here to defend / judge either vendors or people, so please don’t shoot the messenger is the answer is “No API for you”.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [a PDF released by Apple](https://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf), there is a [java tool](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/Autoingestion.class.zip) to export the data from iTunes connect.

This is to compensate the absence of API for iTunesConnect. Still in late 2017, Apple provides no API for iTunes connect or app review services.

Answer (score 1):

after looking everywhere I did not find a PHP version of the reports API so made my own.

You can check it out on https://github.com/Finnb8r/itunes-connect-sales-api-php .

I realize that this is not an Objective-C wrapper but this link comes out on top when generally looking for an API.